# xymon configuration

Tags: linux, networking, monitoring

I'm still beginner with linux and I really need help.
On my local machine that is in LAN, I have installed xymon-4.3.7. 
When I type in browser http://localhost.localdomain/xymon/xymon.html it appears a xymon man-page with one host - localhost.localdomain and it looks like fine.
In /home/xymon/server/etc there are hosts.cfg and client-local.cfg, but I can't see xymon-client.cfg.
My question is how to add new host to monitor. I know that I should install xymon client on the host I want to monitor, but I don't know how to do that and how to configure server and client.
I there any good tutorial about installing and configuring xymon files except this one http://www.xymon.com/xymon/help/install.html.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you mean with "it appears a xymon man-page".
The page should look like what you see on http://www.xymon.com/xymon/help/install.html in the "Starting Xymon" section.

You do not *need* to install the client on systems.
Some checks are running on the server (e.g. HTTP, ping, etc.) against the remote host.
For this you only need to add the host to hosts.cfg on the server.

That being said, you probably *want* to install the client on all hosts to monitor processes which cannot be checked externally and the load of the servers. How to do that depends on which OS you are using.
There are Debian packages of the client available at http://sourceforge.net/projects/xymon/files/Xymon/4.3.7/
If you are not using Debian, you probably will need to compile your own client, just like the server (see http://xymon.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/xymon/trunk/README.CLIENT?revision=6650&view=markup).

If I remember correctly, the server installation will not deploy the client. So if you want to also monitor your Xymon server, you will need to install the client on it as well.

After you installed and configured (via [xymonclient.cfg](http://www.xymon.com/xymon/help/manpages/man5/xymonclient.cfg.5.html)) the client you will also need to add the new host in [hosts.cfg](http://www.xymon.com/xymon/help/manpages/man5/hosts.cfg.5.html). Otherwise it will show up in the "ghost client" page, but not the monitoring page.

In the past this page helped, but it is a bit outdated now, still maybe it helps:
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/System_Monitoring_with_Xymon/Administration_Guide

Apart from that the official manual is still the best resource:
http://www.xymon.com/xymon/help/xymon-config.html